# what is require.resolve in webpack loader test

Tags: webpack

I am learning this [imports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader) on webpack. I've already built several webpack demo projects by following tutorials.

Here is the code to configure imports-loader:

```
// ./webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: require.resolve("some-module"),
                loader: "imports?this=>window"
            }
        ]
};
```

**My questions:**

1. Normally, the "test" should be a regex expression. What is the `require.resolve("some-module")` here? what does it mean?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`require.resolve("<moduleName>")` [returns string which contains path to the module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve), for example

```
> require.resolve('angular')
/tmp/node_modules/angular/index.js
```

so in your example property `test` will contain string with path to the module `some-module`, by default **webpack** [converts](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/ffd2d37efd3f258be2eb15271b9e8d018c6481fc/lib/LoadersList.js#L22) string to the regular expression so final version of loader config will be something like this:

```
{
  test: /^node_modules\/some-module\/index.js/,
  loader: 'imports?this=>window"
}
```

as you can see this loader will be applied only for one file

Comment: What exactly is the reason for using require.resolve() over just passing a string for things like loaders?

Comment: @EJMason if you pass just a name like "foo" you never know relative to which folder web pack would resolve this name. For example you have an npm library which should be builded by web pack by the client app and ship it through npm. When client would build you library and use your webpack.config  `pwd` would be client project dir so "foo" would be resolved relative to this folder. It means that there are chance that 1. web pack just does not find such loader 2) It resolve client version of such loader

Answer (score 0):

webpack's require.resolve returns module id - webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-resolve

> Module ID is a number in webpack (in contrast to NodeJS where it is a
>   string -- the filename).